# MapActivity sometimes closes without any reson

Tags: android, android-mapview

`MapActivity` often just closes without any reason. No exceptions. No messages in `logcat`!No "Force close" message. It's just disappearing.

Another strange point is that it can close itself without any interaction with it (Activity started -> 30 seconds -> Activity closed itself).

Did anyone had the same problem? Any workarounds?
How do I solve this issue?

P.S.`api level - 7`

Comment: You are getting the force close in the emulator or the device?

Comment: Check carefully your logcat. You should at least have a message about your process PID being terminated.

Comment: @Luis I did. Logcat is working correctly, but there is no messages at all. Like nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like problem is that I'm using debug API key and doing too much requests to `mapView` (`addView` and `removeView`)